# Execute PostBuildEvent after AfterBuild on Visual Studio

Tags: build, msbuild

How do I make the postbuildevent execute AFTER the AfterBuild is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add :

```
   <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Exec Command="$(PostBuildEvent)" />
    </Target>
```

I was actually using Costura VS Package and I wished it automatically did this.Anyway, I've modified the Costura VS Package source code and changed it so that it automatically adds this to the Web.Config.

Thanks.